# Установить значение для всех id

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как установить значение required для всех элементов с id[]

```js
function ok() {
$("#stol").prop("required", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol1">
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol2"><br>
<a onclick="ok()">Установить</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью селектора по атрибуту [id^="stol"], который выбирает все элементы, где id начинается со stol (для наглядности вместо required поставим disabled):

```js
function ok() {
  $('[id^="stol"]').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[1]">
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol[2]"><br>
<a onclick="ok()">Установить</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.

Comment: @Vladislav, рад помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи неуместно использовать `id`, нужно использовать `class`. Класс задаётся для всех похожих элементов, а ID — для одного выделяющегося из этого списка похожих элементов.

```js
function ok() {
  $(".stol").prop("required", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol1" class="stol">
<input type="radio" name="1" id="stol2" class="stol"><br>
<a onclick="ok()">Установить</a>
```